# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesLms_developmentDebugAndroidTest'. > Crashlytics Developer Tools error

Tags: crashlytics

I am facing error in build the code. I have installed crashlytics plugin. 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesLms_developmentDebugAndroidTest'.

> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
>   In root project i have fabric.properties file with secret key. I have mentioned api key in android mainfest file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this... I just put the apiKey also in '

> fabric.properties

' file in the project got the solution

```
apiKey=3dfff1sdsd61e9d73bdfdffdf94c2323232
apiSecret=a5dfdfaccdfdfdfffdac5fb7dssdffe45d65sdsdsd72a65esddddds
```